# Thinkster node.js tutorial

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, router

Question about the profile route, why do we have 2 methods that presumably do the same thing: User.findOne and User.findById? Also what is the order of execution for the router.param and router.get?

```
router.param('username', function(req, res, next, username){
    User.findOne({username: username}).then(function(user){
        if(!user) { return res.sendStatus(404); }

        req.profile = user;

        return next();
    }).catch(next);
});

router.get('/:username', auth.optional, function(req, res, next){
    if(req.payload){
        User.findById(req.payload.id).then(function(user){
            if(!user) { return res.json({profile: req.profile.toProfileJSONFor(false)}); }
            return res.json({profile: req.profile.toProfileJSONFor(user)});
        });
    } else {
        return res.json({profile: req.profile.toProfileJSONFor(false)});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simply put:

FindOne queries the database to match against custom identifiers whereas findById queries the database to match a unique identifier.

Also in Express, the routes you define are matched sequentially in the order that they are defined.

Comment: Why dont we just findById then?